# How To Unnest And Pivot Multiple JSON-like Structures Inside A PySpark DataFrame

Tags: arrays, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, google-analytics, pivot

I'm trying to transform raw "Event" data coming from a Google Analytics account using PySpark. Each "Event" record has a field called "event_params", which contains sub-fields in the form of key-value pairs. Here's an example record:

---

```
| event_date | event_timestamp | event_name | event_params                  
| --------   | --------        | --------   | ----------------------|
| 20230207   | 1675797300185610| Page View  | [{key=engaged_session_event, value={string_value=null,        
                                               int_value=1, float_value=null, double_value=null}},
                                               {key=ga_session_number, value={string_value=null, 
                                               int_value=1, float_value=null, double_value=null}}, 
                                               {key=page_title, value={string_value=BlahBlah,
                                               double_value=null}}]                                |
```

I'd like the final dataset to look something like this:

| event_date | event_timestamp | event_name | engaged_session_event | ga_session_number | page_title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230207 | 1675797300185610 | Page View | 1 | 1 | BlahBlah |

I've tried converting the "event_params" field to ArrayType, StructType, and a JSON string, but I'm unable to even extract the individual "key" fields. Once I'm able to do that, I will need to disregard the null "values", and pivot the remaining key-value pairs as new fields.

Comment: Can you print ann show the schema of original df, using `.printSchema()`?

Comment: Yes, each field is a string:                                                                                            
 root
 |-- event_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_params: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_previous_timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_value_in_usd: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_bundle_sequence_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_server_timestamp_offset: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)

Comment: One problem is the string has unquoted values, can you check if you can store it with quotes and then we can take it from there?

Comment: @RonakJain I can't store the values with quotes at this time

Comment: You could transform the string to valid json string thanks to regexp replacement. Or use a UDF to parse it and produce a nested datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

Importing necessary packages

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_replace, split, regexp_extract, from_json, struct, coalesce, max
```

1. Splitting each JSON string values into records

```
df = df \
    .withColumn("event_params", regexp_replace("event_params", "\[", "")) \
    .withColumn("event_params", regexp_replace("event_params", "\]", "")) \
    .withColumn("event_params", regexp_replace("event_params", "\}},", "}}|")) \
    .withColumn("event_params", split("event_params", "\|")) \
    .withColumn("event_params", explode("event_params"))
```

2. Pharsing JSON string values

```
df = df \
    .withColumn("event_params", regexp_replace("event_params", " ", "")) \
    .withColumn("event_params", regexp_replace("event_params", "=", ":")) \
    .withColumn("event_params", regexp_replace("event_params", ",", "',")) \
    .withColumn("event_params", regexp_replace("event_params", "\{", "{'")) \
    .withColumn("event_params", regexp_replace("event_params", "\}}", "'}}")) \
    .withColumn("event_params", regexp_replace("event_params", ",", ",'")) \
    .withColumn("event_params", regexp_replace("event_params", ":", "':'")) \
    .withColumn("event_params", regexp_replace("event_params", ":'\{", ":{")) \
    .withColumn("event_params", regexp_replace("event_params", "'null'", "null"))
```

3. Convert and extract values from `event_params`

```
df = df \
    .withColumn("event_params", from_json("event_params", MapType(StringType(), StringType()))) \
    .withColumn("event_params_key", col("event_params").getField("key")) \
    .withColumn("event_params_value", col("event_params").getField("value")) \
    .withColumn("event_params_value", from_json("event_params_value", MapType(StringType(), StringType()))) \
```

4. To get pivot output

```
df = df.withColumn("event_params_value", coalesce(
    "event_params_value.string_value",
    "event_params_value.int_value",
    "event_params_value.float_value",
    "event_params_value.double_value",
))

df = df.groupBy(["event_date", "event_timestamp", "event_name"]).pivot("event_params_key").agg(
    max("event_params_value")
)

df.show(truncate=False)
```

**Output:**

```
+----------+----------------+----------+---------------------+-----------------+----------+
|event_date|event_timestamp |event_name|engaged_session_event|ga_session_number|page_title|
+----------+----------------+----------+---------------------+-----------------+----------+
|20230207  |1675797300185610|Page View |1                    |1                |BlahBlah  |
+----------+----------------+----------+---------------------+-----------------+----------+
```

*Note: I am not very good in writing `regexp`, If anyone can do so feel free to reformat the code (2).*

Comment: @aknickel Can you please accept this as answer.